# if, not equals and or help (not sure which)

Tags: c#

I am trying to ask if the input is a legitimate numerical variable. I have tried it this way(where its displays the wrong output as shown), with == and else(where its says else is wrong) and don't know why it isn't working. Any suggestions or other ways of trying to do this would be much appreciated.

```
static void start()
{
    // start of broken code

    Console.WriteLine("Please select a variable type");
    string selection = Console.ReadLine();
    if ((selection != "short") || (selection != "ushort") || (selection != "int") || (selection != "uint") || (selection != "byte") || (selection != "long") || (selection != "ulong"));
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a correct form of variable");
        Console.WriteLine("Let's try this again");
        start();
    }

    // end of broken code

    Console.WriteLine("You selected ", selection);
    Console.WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y/N)");
    string sure = Console.ReadLine();
    if (sure == "Y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Let's begin!");
        calculator();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Let's try this again");
        start();
    }
}
```

Output:
Please select a variable type
int //what i have entered
That is not a correct form of variable
Lets try this again
Please select a variable type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '&&' instead of '||'  the evaluation returns true if any of those conditions returns true which guarantees it to fail as it can only be one option.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 issues with this line:

```
if ((selection != "short") || (selection != "ushort") || (selection != "int") || (selection != "uint") || (selection != "byte") || (selection != "long") || (selection != "ulong"));
```

**|| or &&**

This line, in plain English, is saying, *if the user's selection is not "short", **or** it is not "ushort", etc.* No matter what selection is it cannot be both of those - so you'll always get the message "That is not a correct form of variable".

Instead you want code that checks *if the user's selection is not "short", **and** it is not "ushort", etc.* So if the selection matches any one of the allowed possibilities, you'll continue on to the confirmation step.

**; after an if condition**

There is a `;` at the end of the line which shouldn't be there. It has the effect of putting in an empty block for the condition body, and the code which should have been in the condition body will always execute regardless of the result of the condition. So your code

```
if ((selection != "short") && (selection != "ushort") ... );
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a correct form of variable"); 
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if ((selection != "short") && (selection != "ushort") ... )
{} 

Console.WriteLine("That is not a correct form of variable");
```

Remove the semi-colon and it will behave as expected.

```
if ((selection != "short") && (selection != "ushort") ... )
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a correct form of variable"); 
}
```

Comment: I have done as you suggested however the console still returns that 'int' is not a valid variable.
    Console.WriteLine("Please select a variable type");
            string selection = Console.ReadLine();
            if ((selection != "short") && (selection != "ushort") && (selection != "int") && (selection != "uint") && (selection != "byte") && (selection != "long") && (selection != "ulong"));
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a correct form of variable");
                Console.WriteLine("Let's try this again");
                start();
           }